# link:before pseudo-element not clickable after the text wraps

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am inserting an arrow before a link to indicate that clicking will expand the section. The arrow is part of an icon font and is prepended using :before. This link is, itself, the first 'li' of a series that are floated left. (clicking the like will show a hidden container - it won't have any effect on the list) The basic structure is this:

```
<ul>
    <li> <!--Floats left -->
        <a href="link.com" class='prepend-arrow'>Link text</a>
    </li>
    <li> <!--Floats left -->
        Some text
    </li>
    <li> <!--Floats left -->
        Some more text
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The CSS for 'prepend-arrow' is basically:

```
.prepend-arrow:before {
    font-family: 'myIconFont'
    content: '}'
}
```

Normally, this list of items will fit in its container without wrapping and you can click on both 'Link text' and the arrow that precedes it to trigger the link. When the text is localized, though, sometimes it will cause some of the list items to wrap to a second line. 
When that happens, the link behaves normally but the arrow preceding it is no longer clickable.

Admittedly, this is a very minor problem (even in our tester's mind) and I can fall back on just inserting a span in the link with a background image but if there is any way fix the 'broken' link behavior of the pseudo-element when the list has wrapped to multiple lines without adding more markup, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `::before`?

Comment: I've seen both :before and ::before but I'm not sure what the difference is. :before accomplishes what I need but I'll look into if maybe that is having an effect.

Comment: By the way, its possible this is an IE8 only bug.

Comment: That is correct. If you look here http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore you see that IE8 only has partial support for pseudo-elements.

Comment: And btw, the difference between `:before` and `::before` seems to be that the latter is CSS3 syntax, and `:before` is CSS2 syntax.